# limit_except in kubernetes-nginx is not working

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have configured nginx-ingress-controller in kubernetes and I am trying to achieve method based routing from kubernetes.

This is my ingress.yaml file below:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cafe-ingress-with-annotations
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      location /tea {
         limit_except GET {
            deny all;
         }
      }
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cafe.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /tea
        backend:
          serviceName: tea-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /coffee
        backend:
          serviceName: coffee-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

according to the annotation defined it is supposed to block all other methods like POST/DELETE...etc except GET method. But it is not denying any of the methods. Please help me how can I achieve method based routing using limit_except in nginx.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet), the `configuration-snippet` annotation is used for adding an additional configuration to the NGINX location.

If you want to add **custom locations** in the `server` block, you need to use `server-snippet` annotation. As you can read [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet):

> Using the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet` it is
> possible to add custom configuration in the server configuration
> block.

The following `Ingress` manifest should work:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cafe-ingress-with-annotations
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location /tea {
         limit_except GET {
            deny all;
         }
      }
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cafe.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /tea
        backend:
          serviceName: tea-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /coffee
        backend:
          serviceName: coffee-svc
          servicePort: 80
```